# Can we set up a shortcut to run latex in LibreOfiice?

Tags: libreoffice

In using TexMaths in LibreOfiice we always have to click the button "LaTex" so as to display what we type. However, it is cumbersome to click and click the mouse.

I have found no shortcut for clicking "LaTex", so I am wondering can we manually set up a keyboard shortcut for running latex?

Thanks so much for your immeasurable help!

Comment: You don't mean Alt+L, do you?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Thanks so much. Well, yes, I meant it. But how can I change the shortcut, for the default one is somewhat inconvenient for me.

Comment: It would have to be a combination, what would be convenient for example?

Comment: Yes, "ctrl + E" for instance.

Comment: trying something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key combination is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

To change it to (for example) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, you can use xdotool: with which you can simulate (a.o.) keys or key combinations:

- Install `xdotool`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xdotool
  ```
- Then open your keyboard settings: "System Preferences" > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts"
- Add the following command:

  ```
  xdotool key Alt_L+key l
  ```

  give it the shortcut combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (click at the right side of the row)

Then it should work.

Comment: @Comeseeconquer did you manage?

Comment: For me `Alt+L` opens the Slide menu, not Texmaths...